# how to open another window after time?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a Text Editor in javaFX and I want a little StartUp Window before the Text Editor opens.
I want that the StartUp Window is closing after Time and then the Text Editor window opens.
The problem is, the StartUp Window isn't showing when I start the program. And when the time is over, the TextEditor window is showing shortly but then the program is crashing and shows me the Syntax-Error:

InvocationTargetException

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

        MainWindow.openAnother(primaryStage);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 200));
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

MainWindow Class:

```java
package sample;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainWindow {

    public static void openAnother(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4345);
            primaryStage.close();
            Fenster(primaryStage);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) { }
    }

    public static void Fenster(Stage nextStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        //TODO TextEditor-Code

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        nextStage.setScene(scene);
        nextStage.setFullScreen(true);
        nextStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at `PauseTransition`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task. You will not need `pause.playFromStart(); // loop again`.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: .. and stick to java naming conventions, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Timelines.

This example launches a splash screen stage (primaryStage), then three seconds later the textEditorStage shows and then after one second the splash screen stage will close.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Example extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new AnchorPane(), 200, 200));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Splash Screen");
    primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    primaryStage.show();

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(3000), event -> {
      Stage textEditorStage = new Stage();
      textEditorStage.setScene(new Scene(new AnchorPane(), 400, 400));
      textEditorStage.setTitle("Text Editor");
      textEditorStage.show();
      Timeline timeline2 = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), event2 -> {
        primaryStage.close();
      }));
      timeline2.play();
    }));
    timeline.play();
  }
}
```